# Pypandoc error , RuntimeError: Pandoc died with exitcode "47" during conversion: b'pdflatex not found

Tags: python-3.x, pandoc, pypandoc

First time posting here,by the way, i've got an issue with this particular line of Python (3.6) code:

`file_converted = pandoc.convert_file(PATH_TO_ODT, 'pdf', format="odt", outputfile=file_name + ".pdf", extra_args=['--pdf-engine=pdflatex'])`

When i execute the script (to convert a .odt file to a .pdf file) , i encounter the following error :

`RuntimeError: Pandoc died with exitcode "47" during conversion: b'pdflatex not found. Please select a different --pdf-engine or install pdflatex`

Basically i understand that i need "pdflatex" , but after i've installed it via pip with the command

`pip install pdflatex`, the execution produce the same error message, what i should do or check? 
thank you all.

Comment: Using another pdf-engines among the names pypadoc itself support it produces antoher error: `RuntimeError: Pandoc died with exitcode "1" during conversion: b'pdf-engine wkhtmltopdf is not compatible with output format latex`

Comment: I'm using **ubuntu 18.04**  , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pypandoc, which simply calls the `pandoc` commandline program, which in turn calls `pdflatex`, you should probably install LaTeX system-wide. On Ubuntu, that is:

```
sudo apt install texlive
```

Comment: [ IT WORKS ] After the installing of texlive as you suggested me, i've run the following line of code `pandoc.convert_file(PATH_TO_ODT, 'pdf', format="odt", outputfile="<file_name>.pdf", extra_args=['--pdf-engine=pdflatex'])` , and it finally works. @mb21 thank you very much, straight to the point and effective. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MB21:: Pandoc actually does its own conversion - very involved algorithm. I viewed a presentation of the main author (John MacFarlene) recently, pandoc actually translates the source to it's own internal format, AST. From AST format, it is able to convert to a long list of document formats. So, pandoc doesn't just invoke pdflatex.